# Compare two pictures to determine whether there is the same object inside

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am defining a problem: I have two pictures, e.g. two photos with a 1€ coin.
How can I compare the two images to get "yes they contain both a 1€ coin"? of course the test should return false if the second picture contains a 2€ coin.

I tried the openCV methods, but there is nothing so precise.
Also, a ML approach has to handle the issue of recognising two objects in two images without any other previous exposure to them.

**EDIT** I noted the question is a bit too vague: I am trying to redefine it here a bit.

Given two images, how do I write a boolean function `are_the_same(img1, img2)` returning `True` if both images contain the same object?

Here what I tried so far:

1. SIFT, you find keypoints in images and if a certain number of them matches you state they contain the same object.
2. CNN siamese network, you train your network to encode same object pictures to close points in the embedding space, and different object images to points that are far from each other in the embedding space.

Comment: Have you tried SIFT? Also this is a way to broad question. SO is not there for research purposes

Comment: Frankly speaking, I do not understand why you do not want to use ML? I think it would be very easy to provide CNN binary classifier for this problem. As you mentioned, your problem is to determine if there is a 1€ coin in the picture.

Comment: yes, @SlawomirOrlowski, thank you. I already have trained a binary classifier and it works. -i am trying another approach because it is easier to generalise to for example to "this two fingerprints are the same?" In other words I am trying to write down a system comparing two images having seen only two images, not a bunch of training images.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on what types of images you have, but if it's clear top down images, you can use the goldish band/center to distinguish between them.

First a mask is made based on the goldish color. (You'll probably have to make the color range more specific - I had an easy image. I used [this convenient script](https://github.com/twenty-twenty/opencv_basic_color_separator) to determine the color range.) Next some noise is removed and then contours are detected. Contours that have no child- or parent-contour are the solid center of e €2 coin. Contours with a child but no parent are the band of a €1 coin. Contours with a parent but no child are the center of a €1 coin and are ignored.

€2 gets drawn red, €1 blue.

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# load image
img = cv2.imread("E1E2.jpg")
# Convert to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# define range wanted color in HSV
lower_val = np.array([0,25,0]) 
upper_val = np.array([179,255,255])

# Threshold the HSV image to get only goldish colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_val, upper_val)

# remove noise
kernel = np.ones((5,5))
mask_open = cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel)
mask_close = cv2.morphologyEx(mask_open,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel)

# find contours
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(mask_close,cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# loop through contours, check hierarchy, draw contours
for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
    (prev, nxt, child, parent) = hier[0][i]
    if child == -1 and parent == -1 :
        # €2
        cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt],0,(0,0,255), 3)
    if child != -1 and parent == -1 :
        # €1
        cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt],0,(255,0,0), 3)

# display image
cv2.imshow("Res", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```